# Handle sending 1000s of reservations to a web-service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an asmx web service that gets hit by 1000s of reservations per day.
They are distributed by a console app that distributes them across 3 different servers.

The console app is a multi-threaded app.  The reservations are first queued and then submitted to the endpoint.  The problem is that it is running super slow, for example, a reservation that is queued, can take over an hour to get to the endpoint.

I don't know if the reservation is being held in the queue long or what the exact problem is.  Are there specific areas in code I can look to see what is causing this or any type of profilers that can measure this or tell me where the bottle neck is?

Comment: Have you look into traditional load balancing techniques rather than having a console application (that I guess you've written) that does this task? you could *probably* find a faster/better solution, i.e having a number of IIS servers with a LB in front, eliminating the bottleneck in your console app

Comment: It does utilize load balancing already. The console's app responsibility is to just get the reservations from the database and queue them up.

Comment: Use a debugger, stop the app at a random time and check what the different threads are doing: Are they doing anything at all? Are they stuck creating a connection? Are they waiting for the answer from the remote system? Are they in a tight loop doing some computation? Or monitor the network traffic to see what's going on.

Comment: I can't stop the debugger or debug it.  Live clients are using this.  What can I used to monitor the network traffic?

Comment: See [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), it might help you monitor network traffic, cpu usage, etc

Comment: For reference, 1000 reservations/day is about 1 every 68 seconds.  Even at 10 times that, you shouldn't be having enough load to require 3 servers... WTF are you doing that takes that kind of resources?

Comment: I just used 1000 as a number, it is a lot more than that, I don't have the exact number.

Comment: For clarification, do you have 3 instances of the console app and a load balancer at the network level that directs the reservations to the various instances of the console app?  Or do you have one console app that acts as "load balancer" and distributes the reservations to the various servers?

Comment: @peter - 3 instances of the console app and a load balancer at the network level.